# Trouble with 3d model when open with unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 3d-modelling, 3d-model

I used zbrush, substance painter to create this model. After I'm done with everything it looks awesome but when I open it with unity I have this problem. I tried everything but can't find what causing this. I have attached photos.

Please help me.

You can see from here that some of the color is removed:

[image: You can see from here that some of the color is removed]

UV mapping 3d model of skeleton:

[image: UV mapping 3d model of skeleton]

Comment: When high poly models above 65,000 poly's are brought into Unity 5, they are broken into more than one model. If this is the case then add your material to the other part of the model. If not can you add a photo of the render from Substance Painter.

Comment: thank you for replying. THis is what i got from substance painer http://i117.photobucket.com/albums/o43/mongolbaawar/14724039_1218995321471858_860151457_o_zps8f8kwddp.jpg  http://i117.photobucket.com/albums/o43/mongolbaawar/14625470_1218995214805202_874598330_n_zpsc8fr8qhk.jpg

Comment: i have same issue even i reduce he polycount to 60k

Comment: What were your export settings from Substance Painter, and are you sure your tiling is 1,1 on your material in Unity? Hard to say what has happened from Substance to Unity without seeing the entire workflow. Check your normal map to ensure it is set as a normal map type not a texture type. Other thing I would check, because your model is broken up into multiple parts in unity is that every subsection of that model has the same material attached. (First picture you posted, you can see the multiple parts of the one model)

Comment: I tried to export my model without substance painter too and i got same result.

Comment: Hello ALan-Dean Simonds thank you for your reply. Those missing layers gone when i merge all the subtools together. But i need separated skeleton.

Comment: Can you not add the material to all the sections in unity? You shouldn't need to merge.

Comment: Thanks for your reply friend. I have tried it too. Seems not working either

Comment: I would actually have to look at the file as it could be many things, sorry I could not help you out further. Find a tutorial on exporting from Substance Painter to Unity and follow it through. Maybe there is a step you are missing. Good luck and I hope you get it working, the model looks really good.